# Drupal jquery.slicebox.js conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7, conflict

I currently have the slicebox library being used on a drupal 7 website.
It's not a module and it's being added to a page content-type in hardcoded version:

```
<?php
drupal_add_js(path_to_theme().'/js/no_bug_jquery.slicebox.min.js', 'file');
drupal_add_js(path_to_theme().'/js/no_bug_jquery.slicebox.js', 'file');
 ?>
```

My problem is that the 1st file (jquery.slicebox.min.js) is in conflict with other .js scripts found on this page.

If I remove that 1st file, the other scripts work fine but I can't display the slicebox anymore.

Can someone give me a hint how to proceed with that conflict?
Cheers,
Michael

Comment: Hi @mmiguel . Are both scripts doing the same thing, right ? Paste the error here, maybe it can help us figure out more.

Comment: Hi Claudiu, May be if you look at those 2 links that can help you get an idea of the situation. Where we have the problem is (https://www.castolin.com/content/cement-industry) you can see the slicebox working correctly at the top but at the bottom you see the "No database connection" error. If you go to that page (https://www.castolin.com/content/power-industry) where I remove the "drupal_add_js(path_to_theme().'/js/no_bug_jquery.slicebox.js', 'file');" you can see that we have the database connection below but the slicebox isn't shown at the top. Hope that helps you out